# Using Ajax.BeginForm form within a Partial View does not bind my model data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, razor, asp.net-mvc-partialview, ajax.beginform

I have a partial view and it contains the following :

```
@using(Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Upload", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" }))
{
    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Content.Text, new { cols = "5", rows = "5" })
}
```

When I hit the submit button I only get null values in my controller?  The following however does work :

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Create", "Upload", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Content.Text, new { cols = "5", rows = "5" })
}
```

Is there some limitation around having an Ajax.BeginForm inside a partial view that I'm not aware of or should this work?